# PHP Mysqli insert POINT to column

Tags: mysql, insert, point

I am trying to store longitude and latitude in a mysql table of datatype POINT using following code:-

```
$name = $_POST['name']
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$long = $_POST['longi'];
$location = 'POINT('.$lat."".$long.')';
$sql = "insert into `metrix` (`name`, `coord`) values ('".$name.", '".$location."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (empty($result)) {
Echo mysqli_error($con);}
```

and it gives following MySql syntax error:-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'POINT(13,132)')' at line 1

What is the correct way of doing this?

thank you

Comment: POINT is a function and you do not need to wrap with single quote, it should be as `".$location."`

Comment: Don't use variable substitution in the first place, use a prepared statement.

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL injection because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quote from `location` because `POINT` is function and Put single quote before and after name.

```
$sql = "insert into `metrix` (`name`, `coord`) values ('".$name."', ".$location.")";
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes as `Point` is a function

```
$sql = "insert into `metrix` (`name`, `coord`) values ('".$name."', ".$location.")";
```

Also I would recommend you to use Prepared statement as your present query is very much prone to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You miss an single qoute after `".$name."`:

```
$sql = "insert into `metrix` (`name`, `coord`) values ('".$name."', ".$location.")";
```

and remove the single quotes arround `".$location."` because `POINT`is a function and not a string.

And you should use prepared statements.